# Symmetry group of a cube: $O_h \cong O \times C_2$

Tags: group-theory

I want to proof that the total symmetry group (reflections and rotations) denoted by $O_h$ is given by the direct product of the rotation symmetry group of a cube $O$ and the cyclic group $C_2$ so $O_h \cong O\times C_2$. However I have no idea how to proof this formally? I found all the elements of $O$ already but I think it is a tedious job to check whether $O$ and $C_2$ are normal subgroups of $O_h$ and so on. Is there a quicker or more handy way to show this?

Comment: To show that $O$ is normal, note that a subgroup of index $2$ is always normal. For the $C_2$ part, check that the symmetry mapping every point to its antipodal point is actually central.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit.** My answer below is wrong. As @verret comments, the inversion through the center of the cube generates a normal subgroup of order $2$.

The wikipedia page offers several ways to see this. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry

---

There is no (easy) proof because it's not true. The group of symmetries of a cube has a normal subgroup of index $2$ consisting of all proper rotations but no normal subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: Why is $C_2$ not a normal subgroup?

Comment: If you rotate, reflect through a mirror and rotate back you get a different reflection.  If you disagree, please [edit] the question to tell us what symmetry operation you have in mind for the generator of your subgroup isomorphic to $C_2$.

Comment: This is wrong, mapping every point of the cube to its antipodal point is a central reflection.

Comment: Not all "reflections" are reflections through a plane. It might be better to call them orientation-reversing symmetries.

Comment: @verret You are right of course and I just learned something I should have known. Thank you.  I think you should post your comment as an answer. I will leave my wrong answer up (edited) as a cautionary tale.